# How to get average time in Cognos 11

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I am working on a data where I have to calculate average time attendance for days of the week or month

Our Data source is Cognos 11

how to get average time in Cognos 11?

Comment: Is this a relational model or DMR etc?

Comment: Do you want help with just the average?
Or do you want help also with calculating the time attendance?

Comment: I have time attendance and I want to calculate the average time in, time out and work hour for each employee

Comment: Khalid thanks for the explanation, updated my answer to show for time in aka start time

Comment: following up, any luck?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a list with day of week, etc and your metric - calculated time
- Group by day of week
- Select from the swing out menu (I think it's the third option) Summarize, then choose average

Depending on the data source/database you will want to convert your start times to the lowest level (maybe minutes)
Either use a timediff function or if you have to, build it yourself (see below for suggestions on how to do that)

To build the number of minutes yourself, see if there are functions like Hour() and Minute() to deconstruct this.

```
Hours from time = hour([Start Time])
```

Take the hours and divide by 60

Add this to the minutes.  Now you have total minutes

```
Total Minutes = ([Hours from time] * 60) + [Minute]
```

Take the average across the users (or whatever grouping you want) to get the average time per week

```
Average Minutes = average([Total Minutes] for [Work Date])
```

Then take the average minutes and convert that back to the time